# how to make a query not depending on the conditions in where clause when they are null in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, null, where-clause

I'd like to make a query from which the result is not depending on the conditions in where clause when conditions are null while it is depending on the conditions when they are not null.

A query I made is

```
select * from mytable where (num_lot = :num_lot or :num_lot is null) and date_work between :date_start and :date_stop
```

When `:num_lot` is null, the result was not depending on the num_lot, which was what I wanted.
But `:date_start` and `:date_stop` was null, no rows were returned rather than not depending on :date_start and :date_stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
    num_lot=COALESCE(:num_lot,num_lot) AND
    date_work BETWEEN COALESCE(:date_start,date_work) and COALESCE(:date_stop,date_work)
```

when the verified value is NULL it is replaced with the column value i.e. always true.

Comment: I have learned from you that if condition are equal to column name(i.e date_work = date_work), it returns all the rows to meet where clause. Am I right?

Comment: If you have condition like `WHERE 1 = 1` or `WHERE col_1 = col_1`, all rows from `SELECT` will be selected. The idea here with `COALESCE` is to return right value to have positive result in case of NULL. In MS-SQL there is `ISNULL()` function which works like `COALESCE` with 2 arguments but it is shorter.

Comment: @i486 WHERE col_1 = col_1 does not return all the rows of the table if col_1 contains null values.

Comment: @forpas I agree but in this question such case is not expected. Otherwise `date_work BETWEEN ...` will also skip the row when `date_work` is NULL.

Comment: @i486 we don't know if such case is expected. This is why such a condition must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to check if both `:date_start` and `:date_stop` are `null`:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where (num_lot = :num_lot or :num_lot is null) 
and (date_work between :date_start and :date_stop or coalesce(:date_start, :date_stop) is null)
```

or:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where (num_lot = :num_lot or :num_lot is null) 
and ((date_work between :date_start and :date_stop) or (:date_start is null and  :date_stop is null))
```

Comment: @i486 the question is about not depending on the parameters :num_lot and :date_start and :date_stop when they are null. So if all of them are null then the query should return all the rows of the table. If only :date_start and :date_stop are null then the query should return all the rows that satisfy only the condition: `where num_lot = :num_lot`

Comment: Ok, I removed my comment. Read the last lines of question after my comment was sent.

Comment: Why `:date_start is null and  :date_stop is null` and not `OR` between them?